# Pass data to AppDelegate

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates

I wonder how to pass data back to AppDelegate. Let's say I have this scheme

```
AppDelegate - > RootViewController -> FirstViewController -> SecondViewController.
```

The SecondViewController have data which should be saved when AppDelegate applicationWillTerminate method is called. I know that I can use singleton to share data in the application but I don't like this approach. Notification seems will not work in this scenario.

What can you recommend me ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this should get that delegate.

```
AppDelegate * delegate =(AppDelegate*) [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate
[delegate callSomeMethod:someData];
```

Comment: Thanks. I understand now. Is it possible  pass data directly to applicationDidEnterBackground ?

Comment: you can call that method on the delegate if you want.  but that seems like and odd thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

An other suggestion for you. Within your AppDelegate.h class you could create a class method like the following:

```
+ (AppDelegate *)getAppDelegate;
```

and then in your AppDelegate.m

```
+ (AppDelegate *)getAppDelegate
{
    return (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
}
```

Now you can access that delegate wherever you want like (after having imported AppDelagate.h).

```
AppDelegate* sharedDelegate = [AppDelegate getAppDelegate];
```

A cleaner way could be to create a category and put the code there.

Now my question is: why do you need to save data inside the delegate? Maybe you could use a singleton instead. For further info see [singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html).

Hope it helps.