# Passing an integer to the app delegate from a view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, appdelegate

I have an integer, and I need to send it to the appDelegate file of my application. I tried following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546482/pass-data-to-appdelegate), but it didnt make sense, or go into detail on really how to do it. What is the proper method for doing this? And how will i go about sending it from a view controller, and then using it in the appDelegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you'll want to do is declare a property in your app delegate to hold your integer.

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger myIntegerInAppDelegate;
```

Then you can head over to your view controller. Be sure to import your app delegate's header!

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

You could always access `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];` without importing your app delegate, but it's important to have access to your delegate so that we can cast the delegate of sharedApplication to your app delegate's class so that we can gain access to the additional properties it has declared.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    AppDelegate *myAppDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    myAppDelegate.myIntegerInAppDelegate = 3;
}
```

Then if you want to access this variable from within the app delegate class, you could refer to it as `self.myIntegerInAppDelegate`.

Comment: How would I use the integer in the app delegate?

Comment: I will, but cant test right away sory

Comment: I think you may be misunderstanding the question. Im trying to send a number in my viewController to my appDelegate. Not app delegate to view controller.

Comment: my bad, i was seeing it wrong, but when I log the number in the app delegate, it logs 0. Is this becuase the log is being called befor the number is set? If so, how could I make it work?